# Bind variables in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sqlplus

Is it possible to request a variable directly in the terminal? For example, I want to use command `cat <some-file>`, but I want the terminal to ask what file name to use.
Just like in SQL plus I'm using bind variables for this.

Is there any solution for terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read varname` to wait for user input, and store that input into $varname. Then you pass that variable into cat using `cat $varname`.

Look at some examples [here](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-input.php).